# MongoDB inserts geopoint in the wrong order

Tags: php, json, mongodb, symfony, doctrine-odm

I'm trying to insert a location in MongoDB.
I am aware that the location should be in the longitude , latitude order.
this is my PHP code:

```
...
    $coordinates=new Coordinates();
    $coordinates->setLng($lng);
    $coordinates->setLat($lat);
    $hospitals->setCoordinates($coordinates);
...
```

When flushing I get this error :

> insertDocument :: caused by :: 16755 Can't extract geo keys from
>   object, malformed geometry?: { _id:
>   ObjectId('54510e88211b6f133e8b4573'), coordinates: { lat:
>   35.72701023223023, lng: 137.094778418541 },

Why did the coordinates flip the order ? I set them to be longitude latitude , why is the object inverted ?
I was precise when creating the object that longitude is before latitude.
Help please

Comment: Well `setLng` and `setLat` and `setCoordinates` are not MongoDB driver methods. Perhaps explain the library you are using. Or the code you have implemented. This does not deserve an upvote in this form. Bad Dog to whoever did that.

Comment: Maybe I forgot to mention that I'm using ODM doctrine

Comment: Might have helped. A version perhaps? Is this possibly leading to who you really **should** be asking about a serialization problem then?

Comment: Yeah maybe, I'll try to debug it myself now that you mentioned serialization

Comment: Yeah well your data format is not exactly ongoing supported by the look of it. You should be moving to GeoJSON for storage and forget any "leagcy" storage formats of array or "key/value" pairs. Could be the fault of the ODM though. Bad ODM. Sit down. Bad ODM.

Comment: is this documented anywhere?

Comment: MongoDB 2.6 "Gently Suggests" that GeoJSON is the way to go. It's not official ( coz that's breaking API ). But GeoJSON is kind of a **standard**. Stick with standards.

Comment: K! Got that Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [2d indexing documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/2d/#points-on-a-2d-plane) advises using longitude/latitude tuples instead of embedded objects, as you have better control over the field ordering.

> Arrays are preferred as certain languages do not guarantee associative map ordering.

In your case, a 2d coordinate value is best mapped as a [Collection](http://doctrine-mongodb-odm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#collection) type in ODM, which will ensure it is stored as a BSON array in MongoDB.

If you are using a `2dsphere` index with GeoJSON values, the field is best mapped as a [Hash](http://doctrine-mongodb-odm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#hash), which will ensure BSON object storage. From there, you can create a GeoJSON value yourself in PHP (my [geojson](https://github.com/jmikola/geojson) library may be helpful). The Hash-mapped route should be more flexible than creating embedded documents with the specific GeoJSON `type` and `coordinates` fields mapped out (see [this Twitter conversation](https://twitter.com/AymaneShuichi/status/527573685402882048) for some discussion on the subject). Ultimately, it would also be nice for ODM to support GeoJSON as a mapped field type (to convert MongoDB BSON objects to/from GeoJSON classes).